# how to select specfic hidden element from a form in a loop in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So basically, my loop outputs four times the html below with different values in $show_id.
Everyform returns the $show_id value of the first form instead of the value of the form when the function is called. How do I fix that ?

my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
function addScore() {
    var show_id = $('#show_id').val();  
    var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
    var score = $('input[name=tvshowrating]:checked').val();
    if(score=='')
    {
        alert('PleaseEnter A Score');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Score...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "showscoreajax.php",
            data:{
                "show_id" : show_id,  
                "user_id" : user_id,
                "score" : score          //we are passing the name value in URL
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#flash").html('Added');
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};

        </script>
```

myhtml

```
     <div id="flash"></div>
        <form id="form3B">
            <div class="your-score">
                <div class="">Your Score</div>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="1" title="1"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="2" title="2"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="3" title="3"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="4" title="4"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="5" title="5"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="6" title="6"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="7" title="7"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="8" title="8"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="9" title="9"/>
                 <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating" value="10" title="10"/>    
                 <input type="hidden" id="show_id" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" /> 
                 <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id ?>" />
                 <span id="hover-test" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
                 <input id="submitscore" type="submit" value="Submit scores!" onclick="addScore()" />  
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate ID's ,,as you are doing it in loop, you will end up with duplicate id's

Comment: There's no loop shown above. Are you outputting all of that markup repetaedly?

Comment: it's not shown but the loop outputs four times the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you cannot have duplicate id's unlike duplicate class you need different ids for each form. something like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="show_id-form3B" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" />
```

Then it will be possible for you to get unique value of each different forms. Some thing like this

```
function addScore(formId) {
var show_id = $('#show_id-'+formId).val();  
var user_id = $('#user_id-'+formId).val();
//add your code

}
```

Comment: I tried to give each form a different name like this:    <form id="form3B<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
but it still doesn't change anything

Comment: not only the form but to the hidden text fields as well. Every id should be unique

Comment: but then I'd need to have four different functions for each different select

Comment: No need call a common function pass a paramater as a formid for example function callMe(formId) and in the function get id something like this $("#show_id-"+formId).val();

Comment: Anychance you could write the code in your answer please? I'm a complete beginner in Javascript and I don't understand it.